# Azure Builds NuGetToolInstaller cache version is outdated, how do I update it?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

At my company, I can't get NuGetToolInstaller task to work in Azure Builds. I think it is having trouble getting out passed the proxy so I just don't use the task and rely on a cached version of NuGet.exe. However, the problem is the cached version is an older version NuGet 4.1.0 and I have no idea how to update it.

I was able to trick it by going to the location of the NuGet.exe file in the 4.1.0 folder and overwriting it with NuGet 5.5.1 version. Seems kludgy to me.

**My question:**
What's the correct way to update the NuGet.exe in cache used by the **build agent folder?**

**Bonus:**
I have proxy credentials, how do I make the NuGetToolInstaller work?

[image]

Comment: Correct my if I'm worng. The case you describe is from self hosted agent. Did you try uninstall all nuget apart of the one you need and restart agent to catch new capabilities?

Comment: You are correct that I'm using a self-hosted agent.

Comment: I don't see where NuGet is installed on my brand new server. I download the build agent from Azure DevOps and run it interactively. When I inspect the tools in the build folder I see Nuget 3.3.0 in the externals folder and that's it. It isn't until I run a build for the first time that the 4.1.0 gets pulled in and I have no idea where in cache it's coming from (I omitted the NuGetToolInstaller from script so it has to be getting it locally right?)

Comment: I would recommend you to install nuget on your own using installer and then restart the agent.

Comment: @Rod After downloading NuGet 5.5.1 to your local, you can set the local path of nuget.exe into your path environment variable (Copy the location of nuget.exe > Navigate to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables). Then directly call nuget.exe through cmd task in azure devops.

Comment: @Rod Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Are you saying not to use the NuGetCommand task?

Comment: @Rod Yes, only cmd task is needed.

Comment: How would I call NuGet on cmd task to do what NuGetCommandTask does

Comment: @Rod Since the local path of NuGet.exe is set into path environment variable, so when using self-hosted agent, you can view the current version via `nuget` in cmd and directly use nuget command e.g. `nuget.exe restore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround , after downloading NuGet 5.5.1 to your local, you can set the local path of nuget.exe into your path environment variable (Copy the location of nuget.exe > Navigate to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables). Then when using self-hosted agent , you can directly call nuget command through cmd task in azure devops.